# How to use 'order' in CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to order a set of results but for some reason it doesn't get ordered properly. Am i making some kind of a mistake here?

```
$quotations = $this->Quotations->find()
    ->select(['Quotations.id' , 'Quotations.created' , 
'Quotations.supplier_id' , 'Quotations.approval' , 
        'Quotations.region'  ,'Quotations.ponumber' , 'Suppliers.id' , 
'Suppliers.name'])
    ->leftJoinWith('Suppliers')
    ->order(['Quotations.created' => 'DESC'])
    ->toArray();
```

Using CakePHP3 3.5.2

Comment: Your query is fine, what do you mean by "ordered properly"? is it ordered by Quotations.id DESC instead of Quotations.created DESC? In which type is your created property?

Comment: Yes it's ordered by  Quotations.id DESC

Comment: @SamHecquet any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything wrong. To help your debugging, you should also replace `toArray()` by `toSql()` and see how the SQL query looks like
You should try the same query without the `leftJoinWith`.

Comment: @SamHecquet ah alright. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Would need to see the output & assuming 'created' is using Cake's automagic TimestampBehavior; My guess is that it works as expected but you're noticing your ID's in perfect descending order from high to low. This makes sense if you're ordering by created DESC since your latest created date will be the highest ID, next record will be the second highest ID, created the second last... And so on